# How to add JavaScript to a specific View if I don't know the node?

Tags: javascript

I've seen the answer here using the NID but I don't know this, I only have the URL. Is there is another way to do this please?

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    if($vars['nid'] == 'XX'){
      drupal_add_js('path/to/js/file.js');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out hook_views_pre_render https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x

That provides a view object where you could retrieve the machine name of your view and add your drupal_add_js when its the relevant view being loaded

Comment: Hi, thank you. I've include a function in the views.api.php file, but where do I find the result?

(sorry have never done this before)

I'm using:

function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_unformatted($vars){
  $view = $vars["view"];
  $id = $view->id();
}